# How to convert base64 to zip and move to server

Tags: javascript, php, jszip

I am using JSZip for zipping some user upload file and store this zip file on a server. `zip_file` contains the zip file which I want to store in a server. `zip_file` is in base64 format so, if I stored it in PHPMyAdmin as `LongText` format, its could not store some zip. Is it possible to convert `zip_file` to zipping and move to a directory? If yes how can do it? Or How to store base64 value in PHPMyAdmin.

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"}).then(function (content) {
   zip_file = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
   //zip_file convert and move to /uploads folder
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set return `type` to `blob`, use `XMLHttpRequest()` to post `Blob` to `php`

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function (content) {
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("POST", "/path/to/server");
   request.send(content);
});
```

at php use `php://input`, see [Beyond $_POST, $_GET and $_FILE: Working with Blob in JavaScript and PHP](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/03/beyond-post-and-get-working-with-blob.html)

```
<?php

  // choose a filename
  $filename = "file.zip";

  // the Blob will be in the input stream, so we use php://input
  $input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
  $file = fopen($filename, 'wb'); 

  // Note: we don't need open and stream to stream, 
  // we could've used file_get_contents and file_put_contents
  stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
  fclose($input);
  fclose($file);

?>
```